# Hibernate HQL. ManyToMany in subquery

Tags: java, hibernate

I have following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Company {
   ....
   @OneToMany
   private List<Product> products = new Arraylist<>();           
   ....
}

@Entity
public class Product {
   ....
   @Column(name="product_key")
   private String productKey; // same value as in ProductCategory
   ....
}

@Entity
public class ProductCategory{
   ....
   @Column(name="product_key")
   private String productKey // same value as in Product
   @ManyToMany 
   @JoinTable (...)
   private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();

   ....
}
```

I want to write query which will return companies with their corresponding categories:

`Company - List<Category>`

I.e. I want aggregate categories of each Product company have.

Currently I end up with this HQL query, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c, 
        (SELECT pc.categories 
         FROM ProductCategories pc 
         LEFT JOIN c.products products
         WHERE pc.productKey IN products.productKey) 
FROM Company c
```

I tried to add virtual `List<Categories>` field to `Company` entity using `@JoinFormula`, but without success (`@JoinFormula` can not be used with List types, only with single values)

Answer (score 0):

I think Your DB design is making the solution hard.

Since company & product has a one to many relationship, the owner of the relation should be product. Therefore you could keep a reference to the company inside each product.

If I were you, I would go with a design like this.

Company Class

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

    @Id
    private int companyId;

}
```

Product Class

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_key")
    private String productKey; // same value as in ProductCategory

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company", nullable = false)
    private Company company;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="products")
    private List<ProductCategory> categories = new ArrayList<ProductCategory>();
}
```

ProductCategory Class

```
 @Entity
    public class ProductCategory {                      

        @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name="ProductWiseCategory", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="cat_name"),
                  inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="product_key") )
        private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
```